# Centering a child of an absolute position div tag

Tags: html, css

Trying to position a horizontal menu over an image.

I have it positioned over the image as of now, but I can't seem to center the li elements to the middle of the screen.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
    <img src="security-people-interior.jpg"/>            
</div>
<div id="menu-outer">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="horizontal-list">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monitoring</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS3:

```
#banner {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

img, #banner {
    width: 100%;
}

#menu-outer {
    background: url(images/bar-bg.jpg) repeat-x;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu {
    ????
}

ul#horizontal-list {
    /*list-style: none;*/;
}

ul#horizontal-list li {
    display: inline;
}

#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: red;
}
```

The only thing I am able to use is float in #menu{} in the css, but obviously float doesn't have centering.

CSS3 isn't my particular favourite to deal with, so any help would be greatful thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options:

- Set the `display` of the `#horizontal-list` element to `inline-block` and then use `text-align: center` on the parent element in order to center it.

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/q44xe0rf/)

  ```
  #menu {
      text-align: center;
  }
  #horizontal-list {
      display: inline-block;
  }
  ```
- Alternatively, using flexboxes:

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zjqdqcnf/)

  ```
  #menu {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, your a life saver. Was stumped on this for a while. Will accept it as answer when I can. Thanks.